# Polygon shape does not show up in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, drawing, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make some shapes with Java, I created two rectangles and they show up normally, but lately I integrated a polygon shape code but it not showing up while running the program. Somebody help in this please!

Here is a screenshot after running:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class shapes extends JPanel{
int midX = 120;
int midY = 60;
int radius[] = {118,40,90,40};
int nPoints = 16;
int[] X = new int[nPoints];
int[] Y = new int[nPoints];
int i;
double max;

public void paintComponent(Graphics gphcs){
super.paintComponent(gphcs);
this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

gphcs.setColor(Color.BLUE);
gphcs.fillRect(25,25,100,30);

gphcs.setColor(Color.GRAY);
gphcs.fillRect(25,65,100,30);

gphcs.setColor(new Color(190,81,215));
gphcs.drawString("This is my text", 25, 120);

for (double current=0.0; i<nPoints; i++)
{
    double x = Math.cos(current*((2*Math.PI)/max))*radius[i % 4];
    double y = Math.sin(current*((2*Math.PI)/max))*radius[i % 4];

    X[i] = (int) x+midX;
    Y[i] = (int) y+midY;
}
gphcs.setColor(Color.RED);
gphcs.fillPolygon(X, Y, nPoints);
}
}
```

Acutally I wanted the polygon to show up as a star shape but it even didn't appear at all!

Thank you..

Comment: Have you tried debugging or printing x and y to ensure the coords look valid?

Comment: You never set the value of 'max' so I'd be expecting an exception due to division by 0 in your for loop

Comment: Perhaps when you divide by max you should really be dividing by nPoints?

Comment: Also current is always 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your polygon co-ordinates are the same. Try

```
for (int i=0; i < nPoints; i++) {
   double x = Math.cos(i * ((2 * Math.PI) / nPoints)) * radius[i % 4];
   double y = Math.sin(i * ((2 * Math.PI) / nPoints)) * radius[i % 4];

   X[i] = (int) x + midX;
   Y[i] = (int) y + midY;
}
```